# android app recommendation for attendance tracking

Tags: android, iphone-app

I am going to coordinate a massive specimen collection exercise among long term care facilities that I need to keep track of whether a specimen is taken or not. I think an android app for tracking attendance may be useful for me to get timely feedback from the colleagues who collect the specimens, I am thinking of the following specification:

1. centralized database storing student information, preferably to be stored in google spreadsheet, I only need to store student ID, and whether is student has attended lesson
2. ability to add new student to the database
3. multiple user access, which means I open a master google spreadsheet and everyone connect to that and mark attendance
4. presence of both android and iphone version.

Any suggestion and request for further clarification is welcome. Thank you.